# combine two scrolls - gallery with horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, gallery, frontend

I'm trying to create a simple gallery with vertical scroll. This scroll should cause two things: 1.move small pictures below the big photo and 2.change the source of the big photo (so it will change the big photo in result). I'm not got at describing what exactly I want to do so here is the code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="bigPhoto">
    <img />
</div>
<ul>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=1' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=2' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=3' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=4' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=5' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=6' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=7' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=8' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=9' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=10' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=12' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=13' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=14' /></li>
    <li><img src='http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg&text=15' /></li>

</ul>
<input type=range id='scroller' />
```

css:

```
ul {
    border:1px solid orange;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    max-height: 50px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;}
li {
   display:inline-block;}
img {
   width:50px;}
.fullSize {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;}
```

js:

```
var smallImages = document.querySelectorAll('li img');
var bigPhotoDiv = document.querySelector('.bigPhoto img');
var scroller = document.querySelector('#scroller');

bigPhotoDiv.src = smallImages[0].src;
bigPhotoDiv.classList.add('fullSize')

scroller.max = smallImages.length-1;
scroller.addEventListener('change', function(event) {
var currentLink = smallImages[scroller.value].src;
bigPhotoDiv.src = currentLink;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0d2z26e1/

Now I have two scrolls, lower for changing my bigPhoto and upper for moving small images. Is it possible to combine them into one?

Comment: You could always hide the browser scroll bar, then set the scroll position using the artificial scroll bar.

Comment: Ok, I did as you said and it almost works. Now the problem is that I want to set the scroll position by function:
my input.value * width of one image. The problem is that the input value is not integer, even if i set the 'step' at '1.0' or '5.0',the value is still something like: 0.9090908893868948

Comment: I tried to use parseInt() function before I multiply the value by width. It doesn't work though.